# The arithmetic of first uncountable ordinal number

Tags: general-topology, well-orders

I think, I know the proof of 1+ω0 = ω0. (ω0 is countable ordinal s.t ω0=[N]). To prove this, I can define a function f: {-1,0,1,2,...}->{0,1,2,...} by f(x)=x+1. But if ω1 is first uncountable ordinal than how can I prove 1+ω1=ω1. Could anyone please give me an idea about this?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Can you think of a way of extending the function you've created past $\omega_0$? (Hint: is there any x with $f(x)=\omega_0$ in your function $f:\mathbb{N}\mapsto\mathbb{N}$?)